# Execution merge with another branch from repo

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

I have the code locally, which is in the master branch, after the command git status, I have a `master`.

My task is to merge master branch with new-feature branch (branch in the repository), but I only have a local master branch. How can I download a new-feature branch, make it merge with the master branch and make a push for new-feature branch.

I know that one of the steps, you will:

```
git checkout new-feature
git merge master
git push
```

But how to get the branch from the repository?

Comment: Did you try out your commands? Assuming you fetched recently it works as you wrote it in the question.

Comment: @musiKk I do not was doing these commands and was doing not a git fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a new-feature branch remotely use

```
git push origin master:new-feature
```

to create a new branch and push the changes in master to it.

If there is a new-feature branch already, commit your changes locally and do cherry-picking

```
git checkout -b new-branch origin/new-feature
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

To get the commit hash use `git log` on master branch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the new-feature branch merged to the local version of master you can simply do

```
'git pull origin new-feature'
```

It will fetch the changes that are on the remote 'new-feature' branch and merge them to your local master branch. After that you can do 'git push origin new-feature' to update the new-feature remote branch.
If you would rather like to create your local new-feature branch, you can do this by typing:

```
'git checkout -b <new-feature>'
```

and then pull the code from remote branch on it.